# Given Bipartite Graph $K(a,b)$ how many cycles at size 4 can be?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Given Bipartite Graph $K(a,b)$ how many cycles in size 4  can be?

As we know $K(a,b)$ is a full Bipartite Graph meaning that for every $vi\in a$ there is an edge to every $v\in b$.

To get a cycle at size 4 I will need to pick one $vi\in a$ that will be connected via edges to $vi,vj\in b$.

Then to both those $vi,vj\in b$, I will pick another, different from the one above, $vj\in a$ that they will connect via edges.

In order to calculate it, I've tried to use combinatorics:

To choose the first $vi\in a$ I will have $a\choose1$ options

To choose the $vi,vj\in b$ I will have $b\choose2$

And to choose the $vj\in a$ I will only have $(a-1)\choose1$.

So the total possibilities that I have will be $a\choose1$ $\cdot$ $b\choose2$ $\cdot$ $(a-1)\choose1$

Is it correct to say that?

Comment: The usual notation for a bipartite graph with part sizes $a$ and $b$ in which every possible edge is present between the two parts is $K_{a,b}$, called the complete bipartite graph with those part sizes.

Comment: Also, when using mathjax do not use \epsilon for pertinence relation, but \in instead.

Comment: Here you go! I've fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first choose the vertices, a distinct pair from the part of size $a$ and a distinct pair from the part of size $b$. (We consider the two parts distinguishable even if they have the same size.)

Those four vertices can be connected in a cycle in only one way, although the cycle could be "oriented" or *directed* in two ways.  Therefore the number of cycles is:

$$ \binom{a}{2} \binom{b}{2} $$

This differs from the count made by the OP.  A small example illustrates that the method used there double counts because the same choice of a pair of vertices in the part of size $a$ occurs twice (in either order).  E.g. take the complete bipartite graph $K_{2,2}$, which has only one $4$-cycle.

Comment: So basically all I needed is to subtract in the number of possibilities from  $a$ that is $2!$.
Thank you for the answer!!